# other activity showed up in place of Main Activity when multiple modules are combined in to a single project in android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, build.gradle

I have many android modules implemented in my project. Each module is added as an independent Android module which can be launched on mobile or an emulator. After working on all the modules. Finally, I wanted to merge all those independent modules into one project and connect everything and make all the modules work as a single app.

To do that, I've replaced `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` with 
    `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` in all the module's gradle file except for the `app/build.gradle` which is the first module in the app and it has `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`in its gradle.

Also, in the `app/manifest.xml` I have this defined in it:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

But, when I launch the app on an emulator or a real device. The activity of the fourth module which is named as `FirstTimeProfileSetup` (i.e. not MainActivity) shows up on the screen as a first screen. when we wait for some time without any operations on the screen, then the `FirstTimeProfileSetup` screen goes off and the MainActivity of the app module will show up.

Below is the manifest.xml file of app module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!--<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />-->


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/app_logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon,android:roundIcon">


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".loginAndSignup.sign_in"
            android:label="sign_in"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Registration" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Below is the manifest of the other module whose activity is showing up first:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.firsttimeusermodule">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!--<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />-->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".FirstTimeProfileSetup"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".ProfilePic"></activity>

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.firsttimeusermodule"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

and below is the build.gradle of app module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.0'
    compile project(path: ':usertype')
    compile project(path: ':firsttimeusermodule')
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and below is the build.gradle file of the other module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
//        applicationId "com.firsttimeusermodule"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Can anyone please helps me resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Here's the screenshot of Merged Manifest:[image]

Comment: Did you check the merged AndroidMenifest.XML?

Comment: Open the Manifest file and click of the tab next to text which says Merged manifest.

Comment: @MRX Thank you for your response :). Do you want me to paste the MergedManifest here?

Comment: No just have a look if the final Menifest file is what you expect to be !!! Just another step to verify before start looking into the solution ..

Comment: @MRX please have a look at the screenshot posted above which is the Merged Manifest tab and help me.

Comment: @MRX what is the next step?